# How to turn off Captcha for search?

Tags: search, captcha

I've installed the Captcha module and I need to remove it from the search button and form (just an unnecessary nuisance there). Captcha configuration allows me to turn it off for specific values of a "Form_ID". I tried that with "search", but I guess the form ID is more complicated than that. What Form_ID(s) do I need to use to get Captcha to stop showing up in search?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a block, the form_id should be:

> search_block_form

and for a page:

> search_form

To easily find this information, install the [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel):

> A suite of modules containing fun for module developers and themers

and use something like this in your theme's template.php file:

```
function myTheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    dpm($form);

}
```

This will show a hierarchical display of all forms on the page - you can then scroll quickly through the info to find what you need. Very handy for searching arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Simple uncheck this "Default challenge on non-listed forms." on admin/config/search/settings